# Aggregate data columns from different tables into one table with query in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, aggregate

I have two tables located in one spreadsheet and I want to get certain columns from each of them and merge them into one table in another spreadsheet using a query in google sheets. And I want to color the data from the second table into a different color so that I will differentiate.  See the [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vJVY5gqG_1qHUtsrcDnagMDH5MhzK5TKYYG4Zj_PkZM/edit?usp=sharing) that I made with sample tables and desired output table.

I tried to write a query like below, but it returned only the data from the first table.

```
=QUERY({
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1vJVY5gqG_1qHUtsrcDnagMDH5MhzK5TKYYG4Zj_PkZM","table1!A2:B"), "SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col2 <> 0 ");
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1vJVY5gqG_1qHUtsrcDnagMDH5MhzK5TKYYG4Zj_PkZM","table2!A2:C"), "SELECT Col2, Col3 WHERE Col3 <> 0 ")
}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 is not null")
```

Can you please help me to write a query for that?

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,{table1!A:B;table2!B2:C},filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>""))
```

OR

```
=query({table1!A:B;index({--table2!B2:B,table2!C2:C})},"Where Col2 is not null")
```

[image]

Comment: table1 has numerical `Column A` and table2 has `numeric-looking-but-text` based `Column B`. query does not react well to mix two different data types in a single column; so it ends up showcasing data from just one table. for more info on this scenario checkout this [article here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mixed-data-type-issue-in-query/)

Comment: Is it possible to color the rows from the second table in different color?

Comment: well that would require you to have an extra identifier column to showcase that this data is coming in from sheet1 and that from sheet2 and so on. then add a conditional formatting rule to mark rows from sheet2

Comment: What if my columns in one table are not in range, I mean the columns are in separate columns (like A2:A, C2:C), how the formula will change in this case? I modified the tables, can you please look at them?

Comment: Updated the formulas and also added one approach (`Cell L1`) to color code rows from sheet2

Comment: the formula in `Q1` matches headers dynamically irrespective of where they are positioned (or moved) in table1 and table2 row headers

Comment: It worked, thanks! I also want to filter column C in table 1 not to be equal to 0, can you please add it to the new formula in cell L1?

Comment: Is it possible to add "shipped" and "unshipped" statuses for column N instead of 1 and 2 to the formula in cell L1? Or maybe to the formula in Q1 as well? Query in Q1 seems very practical, I added a filter by non-zero values(which you provided)to it, and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I made a new tab on your sample sheet called mk_help and placed this formula in cell A1.

Note that column A is hidden now and used for Cond. Formatting:

```
=QUERY({QUERY(table1!A2:C,"select 'table1',A,C");QUERY(table2!A2:D,"select 'table2',B,D")},"where Col2 is not null label Col1'source',Col2'GTIN',Col3'QTY'",1)
```